# SQL Server 2008: Join VIEW with other VIEW: precalculate without resorting to temp tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, query-hints

To perform transformations in my database, I frequently use a chained set of views. Within the views will be common table expressions. For example I would have the following:

```
CREATE VIEW TransformationStep1 AS
    WITH Transformation1A AS (
        SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Bla(Field1) AS Calc FROM Table1
    ),
    Transformation1B AS (
        SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Calc FROM Transformation1A
    )
    SELECT * FROM Transformation1B

CREATE VIEW TransformationStep2 AS
    WITH Transformation2A AS (
        SELECT Field1, Calc FROM TransformationStep1
    ), ....
```

Somewhere near TransformationStep4 the views will become slower as the query plan becomes more complicated. This is expected and OK.

But when I want to join a part of TransformationStep4 to itself, the query will slow down hugely as the optimizer tries to find its way back all the way to the source tables and look for indexes of some kind. Normally this is OK, but sometimes I just want to store my temporary result and join with that because (being the designing human in the story) I for one know that the result table will be quite small, and it will be much faster to join against a "prefetch" of it.

Is there a way for me to write a query hint, that will influence the query plan in such a way that the subquery will be prefetched and then joined against? Otherwise I'll have to resort to temp tables in a stored procedure, but I want to avoid it if I can.

Thanks for any suggestions, also when you think my design sucks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A view is a macro that expands: there is no caching or pre-fetching pre-calculation.

Unless you have indexed views where you can use NOEXPAND.. but these will not wok on ordinary views.

However, you can use inner TOP/ORDER BY to materialise the view too:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (SELECT TOP 2000000000 * FROm TransformationStep2 ORDER BY soemthing) V1
   JOIN
   (SELECT TOP... ) bar on foo.x = bar.x
```

There is nothing magical about a view: it's just text and has no memory or persistence...

Comment: The TOP works! Great, now I can use it to materialize my common table expressions. (I didn't think a view was magical, I just want to be able to manipulate the query optimizer to not recurse into my CTE..)